# Running GRUB From Terminal After Successfully Logging In

Tags: grub2, gnome-terminal

Can I run GNU Grub and go to Grub Prompt after logging in into Desktop ? I mean from Terminal . Using Grub2 By the Way .

[Sample Picture of Unix Terminal after Logging In](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Syqrv.jpg)

**OS : lUbuntu 18.04 x64 (64-Bit)**

Comment: You've not provided any OS/release, and your screen doesn't appear to show `gnome-terminal` as I see it.  It's a LXDE desktop that isn't default now with any Ubuntu or *flavor* of Ubuntu.  You'll need to provide OS/release details, and if you've booted the OS then it's '*way too late*' to operate GNU GRUB which is the Grand Unified Boot Loader - as it's used to boot an OS.

Comment: @guiverc OS Details Provided . Please Support .

Comment: FYI:  Lubuntu 18.04 LTS is no longer supported; refer https://lubuntu.me/bionic-eol/ or https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ where you'll note only Ubuntu Server, Ubuntu Desktop & Ubuntu Cloud come with 5 years of support; *flavors* had shorter lives. I'd suggest using `ubuntu-support-status` to assess the security status of your actual install. Your question is still on-topic here, but consider how much security matters to you and the results of prior command. You're now using Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with LXDE (*not Lubuntu*).

Answer (score 1):

Grub is used to boot an OS, i.e. it runs before the Linux kernel has even started; before a DM (*display manager*) lets you login, etc. and well before the desktop is loaded by the DM.  To return to grub, you need to shutdown the OS and reboot, as it was written to be a bootloader.

Grub = GRand Unified Bootloader. It's used to boot an OS.

Reference - https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/ or https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_GRUB

If you have multiple OSes installed, be they GNU/Linux systems such as Ubuntu, BSD, windows etc.. it will let you select which you will boot & use.  What you're asking for makes no sense in my opinion.  A terminal is a user-process on a OS that is already running, GRUB is used to start an OS, and wasn't intended to be used to run virtual machines.

Comment: To edit suggester: GRUB was capitalized the way it was because that's GNU capitilization.  The DE is a desktop, and I wrote as DEsktop instead of typing DE (*desktop*) as I did with DM.  Sorry if it appears inconsistent.